# Add custom field in order->shipment in Magento

Tags: mysql, magento

I would like to add one more field i.e qty ordered by customer in Order -> Shipment part.Can some one help me on this.

Regards
Vishavdeep Goyal

Comment: do you want to show the new tab on Sales->Shipment....bcoz there is no tab for Order -> Shipment

Comment: No i do not want to show the new tab on sales -> shipment. i just want to show the one additional column of  total qty ordered by the customer if you go to sales -> shipment. and currently showing fields are as: Shipment # Date Shipped Order # Order Date Ship to Name Total Qty

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of how you would like to select "qty ordered by customer" from, but the example bellow shows how to display total_qty_ordered field form sales_flat_order table in Shipment grid:

1) Copy file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php to app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php

2) Modify the _prepareCollection() method

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('order' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales_flat_order')), 'main_table.entity_id = order.entity_id', 'total_qty_ordered');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

2) Modify the _prepareColumns() method and the following code to it

```
$this->addColumn('total_qty_ordered', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Total Qty Ordered'),
            'index' => 'total_qty_ordered',
            'type'  => 'number',
        ));
```